# Excel Solver: Solving based on an average

Tags: excel, vba

I have a parameter in **A1** that influences "**TOTAL**" in a random and very high standard deviation. Lets say **A1** is 2...then **TOTAL** Values could be 1...5...17...3...2..2...etc If **A1** is 1 then **TOTAL** Values could be 1....3...5..15...9...10..etc

I would like solver to figure out which value in **A1** would equate to the best AVERAGE of **TOTAL** after **X** runs. Where I can define **X**.

In my example you can tell that `A1=1` is better on average after **6** runs. However, if you run solver normally it would say `A1=2` is the best, because it produced a value of 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be the kind of problem you solve with solver. Why not write a macro that loops through the values of A1, X times, keeping a running sum of the TOTAL values for each A1? When it's all over, the largest sum is also the largest average.

The inner loop will be something like this:

```
Redim tSum(1 to maxA1)
for i = 1 to maxA1
    tSum(i) = 0
    for j = 1 to X
        [A1] = i
        Application.calculate
        tSum(i) = tSum(i) + TOTAL
    next j
next i
'now step through tSum. The index of the largest value 
' is the value of A1 desired. Put it in a handy cell.
```

It has to be a macro, not a function because it changes A1.